# Adafruit Huzzah espcomm_open failed

Tags: serial, esp8266, adafruit

I recently bought an adafruit huzzah as well as a serial to usb [cable](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954) to connect it to my computer running windows 10. I was able to get the board set up in arduino following the directions found [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-huzzah-esp8266-breakout/using-nodemcu-lua?view=all#using-arduino-ide). I copied and pasted this sketch:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```

into the arduino 1.8.2 IDE, followed these instructions:

> Hold down the GPIO0 button, the red LED will be lit
>
> While holding down GPIO0, click the RESET button
>
> Release RESET, then release GPIO0
>
> When you release the RESET button, the red LED will be lit dimly, this means it's ready to bootload

and tried to upload only to get an error:

In versions 1.6.5 and 2.0.0 of the esp library I get these errors:

```
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_open failed
```

In versions 2.1.0 - 2.3.0 of the esp library, I get these errors:

```
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

I've tried switching the tx and rx leads, I've tried versions 1.6.5-2.3.0 of the esp8266 library. I've also tried it on the other board that I ordered and got the same errors. Any ideas on what could be the problem?

EDIT: I've now tried it on a generic esp-01 board and am having the same issue

Comment: in Arduino IDE, open the serial monitor, click the reset button on the huzzah - do you see anything in the serial monitor - if nothing at all (no text or even garbage characters) then you either: a) have tx/rx connected incorrectly, or b) haven't selected the correct COM port, or c) have a defective huzzah (or you killed it)

Comment: aside: if you like the huzzah, checkout the wemos D1 mini (1/2 price) and the nodeMCU (1/3 price)

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/faq/a01-espcomm_sync-failed.md. If it solves your problem please come back and write an answer to your question to help others who have the same trouble.

Comment: @per1234 I followed the guide and noticed that in my verbose upload output, it's setting the board to nodemcu. Is that normal for a Huzzah?

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the SiLabs CP2104 drivers and reboot.
Make sure you don't have 2 connection (Arduino IDEs, VS Code with PlatformIO, ...) open. Also, I kept pressing the reset button the first time.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-huzzah-esp8266/using-arduino-ide